# A question about isomorphism of direct modules and non isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a ring (having $1$)  and $A,B,A_1,B_1$ are left $R$ modules. If $A+B$ is isomorphic to $A_1+B_1$ and $A$ is isomorphic to $A_1$,
I think $B$ may not be isomorphic to $B_1$.

But I can not give an example, please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with some vector spaces. Take a vector space $V$ of dimension 4, subspaces $A$ and $A_1$ of dimension 3, and find $B,B_1$ of different dimensions satisfying $A+B=V=A_1+B_1$.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: we have $R^{\Bbb N} \oplus R \cong R^{\Bbb N}$ as $R$-modules.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, with $\phi([a],[b]) = ([b],[a])$?